# how can i send a POST request from jquery ajax to a flask view?

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, flask

hope you are having a wonderful day :D
so let me start with explaining what i attend to do: i have one html page (index.html) and one view (/index) the index.html page holds a form in it that on submit will use jquery ajax to send a json object to the /index view 
here is the code for the very simple and straightforward index.html:

```
<body>
<form action="/" method='post'>
    <button id='submit'>submit</button>
</form>

<script src="../static/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function saveMenu() {
        localStorage.setItem("shoppingMenu", JSON.stringify(
            [{"name":"*Kabab Combo Plate","price":10.99,"count":4},
            {"name":"Mixed Grill(Lamb, Chicken, Kefta)","price":14.99,"count":4}]
            ));
    };

    saveMenu();

    function loadMenu() {
        menu = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingMenu"));
        return menu;
    };
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var menu = JSON.stringify(loadMenu());
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                data: menu,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: '{{ url_for("index") }}',
                success: function(m){
                        console.log(m);
                },
                error: function(m){
                    console.log(m);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

and here is the code of the /index view, notice that i added print statements and that is for debugging purposes, you'll see what i mean in just a moment:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        print('header: ', request.headers.get('Content-Type'))
        print('data type: ', type(data))
        print('data = ', data)
        for i in data:
            print(i)
        return 'success'
    return render_template('index.html')
```

now here is what happens when the previous code gets executed:

```
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 143-889-961
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
header:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
data type:  <class 'list'>
data =  [{'name': '*Kabab Combo Plate', 'count': 4, 'price': 10.99}, {'name': 'Mixed Grill(Lamb, Chicken, Kefta)', 'count': 4, 'price': 14.99}]
{'name': '*Kabab Combo Plate', 'count': 4, 'price': 10.99}
{'name': 'Mixed Grill(Lamb, Chicken, Kefta)', 'count': 4, 'price': 14.99}
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
header:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
data type:  <class 'NoneType'>
data =  None
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Orbit\flaskname\app\hello.py", line 25, in index
    for i in data:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

by looking at the print statements output and before the error shows up notice that request.json is working properly and is returning the data that we were expecting but then a `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Oct/2017 21:12:24] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -` shows up and then it looks like the view function is rerunning itself and then the print statements is outputting none as a value of the data variable... does anyone know why this pattern is happening? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, the submit event in a form (that, in this case, happens when you click on the submit button) will redirect to the `action` of the form, as such, you are actually doing two requests (ajax and the default).

To prevent this, fire `event.preventDefault` inside the click handler (and add `event` to the arguments).

```
.click(function(event) {
  // ...
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

You also need to return a json response from the flask view, like this:

```
from flask import jsonify

# ...

  return jsonify('success')
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)). That prevented the traceback error . However ajax is logging the error function `error: function(m){ console.log(m);}` here are the arguments that hold values in the logged error : `readyState: 4`, `responseText: “success”`, `status: 200`, `status: “OK”` you have helped me plenty so far but if you know why the ajax error is showing or if i should care about it please let me know . Thanks again ^^

Comment: That problem is because in the request you're asking for json but returning a string so jQuery throws a parsing error. To fix it, you should return json from the flask view. Updated the answer to show this.

Comment: “Success” now is showing as an alert whenever I submit the form. But as you can tell i used “success” as return value so the code would be simple and easy to understand. How can i return a render_template or redirect(url_for))?

Comment: Did you change anything in the code? You must be using an alert somewhere for success to be showing as an alert. In any case, if you're using ajax, there's no point returning a render_template or redirect as you should expect json back; the path changes or redirects should then be triggered from the js side.

Comment: it is the `success: function(m){ alert(m) }` that is inside the ajax that’s returning what ever i return from the flask view!. Could you please show me how can i change path from js because that’s what i am interested in

Comment: I feel like you must know, what i am trying to do is to take an array from the localStorage and then send it to flask view so i can save it in database using sqlalchemy then when everything goes right a success.html should be returned. That simple!

Comment: `window.location.replace('/success')` is what you can use in the `success` callback.

Comment: Luis you are a flask expert \^-^/. Sorry for the delay I didn’t have an internet access for the past week. You really did save me on that, if you are interested in solving  another flask/ajax dilemma check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101390/form-validate-is-false-when-submit-button-is-preventdefaulted).

Comment: I know that i have overwhelmed you with my questions. Yet i have another issue with the previous solution, it does return the menu array to flask view but the form.validate is now False I don’t know why i tried to serialize it but that didn’t work. Do you know how can i send the menu array and validate the form at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the current pattern by removing the form in the html template:

```
<button id='submit'>submit</button>
```

Let the button alone or put it inside another section if needed, but the form seems to make a parallel request. I will try to link some doc to explaining it better.

Comment: Thank you @PRMoureu that one way of solving the problem but i need to use the form for other purposes so i am keeping it and using the `preventDefault` As Luis suggested so it will simulate not having a form.